# Can I convert a html page to pdf with htmltodoc and LiveDocx without creating a .doc on server?

Tags: php, html, pdf, doc, livedocx

I am trying to use the class htmltodoc in order to create a .pdf from an html page with :
http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/html-to-doc-classes/html-to-doc-classes/html_to_doc.inc.php

And with the library LiveDocx (with Zend) :
http://srhwd.com/documentation/moodle/_mail_merge_8php_source.html

without creating a .doc . Here is my code :

```
$htmltodoc= new HTML_TO_DOC();

$htmltodoc->createDocFromURL("http://www.youtube.com/","google.doc",false);

$mailMerge = new Zend_Service_LiveDocx_MailMerge(
    array (
        'username' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxxxxx'
    )
);

$mailMerge->setLocalTemplate($htmltodoc);

//$mailMerge->setLocalTemplate('template.doc'); Normally, template.doc is registered on server

$mailMerge->createDocument();

$document = $mailMerge->retrieveDocument('pdf');

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=document.pdf');

header('Content-type: application/pdf');

echo $document;
```

But it returns:

> Error HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error)

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: I have to change $mailMerge->setLocalTemplate($htmltodoc) with something but I don't really know what =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert HTML to PDF you could use a PDF lib such as :

- [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)
- [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/) (see [example 6](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php))

Comment: Thank you Adrien, I will try dompdf if I don't manage to fix my problem. But do you have an idea to fix it ?

Comment: You should try to fetch the actual error : when Apache says "Error HTTP 500" you must go to PHP error logs and you will see a more detailed error message.

Comment: Thank you all, dompdf is very simple and efficient ! =)